# How to create Skybox in Qt 3D with C++ or Python?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt3d

Does anyone know how to create basic Skybox in Qt 3D? I'm struggling with [QML example](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qt3drenderer-skybox-skybox-qml.html), and I have no idea how to translate it to C++ or Python.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be nice if you showed some code and asked explicitly what you are struggling with. There are some Qt3D examples that are available in both QML and C++, maybe those can help you get started.

Comment: I decided to quit using Qt 3D last night. It is just a big undocumented mess. I wrote Skybox class in OpenGL in a 30 min. I will check out Qt 3D in a couple of years. Too many basic functionalities are missing or undocumented and developers are for some unknown reason prioritizing QML

Comment: I can feel your frustration, I tried to use in a [university project](https://github.com/florianblume/6d-pat) in 2018 and failed miserable. In the end I went for OpenGL. I now actually rewrote the code in Qt3D again because it does offer a lot of nice features (like object picking, etc.). Translating QML code to C++ is actually pretty simple, you just need to prepend the Q and obtain the corresponding C++ class - in most of the cases. I'll see if I can translate the code for you and post it as an answer.

Comment: Ah and I forgot to mention: the [Qt3D manual tests on GitHub](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/tree/dev/tests/manual) are always a good source of how things work in Qt3D.

Comment: Thank You. That is very cool project! I will probably give it one more try when I find some time, but for now OpenGL is much faster option for me. The reason why I wanted to use Qt 3D is because it will probably, at some point, support different backends like Vulkan or Metal so I won't have to learn those in the future. But right now I feel like figuring out Qt 3D takes more time than to actually learn all of those haha